# Combining multiple objects in one listview

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm working on a XAML-based Windows Phone 8.1 project. My `MainPage` has a Pivot control, the first item of which is designed to be a "dashboard" of some sort, combining multiple kinds of data such as events and to-dos.

For this particular purpose I have an `Event` and a `To-do` model classes (not the actual name, but you get the idea), as I am using MVVMLight to run the show.

I have currently set up a `ListView` in a pivot item in MainPage.xaml. I was wondering how can I make it work such that all items with objects `Event` and `To-do` are at one single pivot item.

I've looked around and found CompositeCollection, but it's only on WPF, not on WinRT yet. I tried dealing with [Midgard.CompositeCollection](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/Midgard.CompositeCollection) but the data doesn't show up, and I don't understand how can I style these independent kinds of data differently.

Are there any techniques on combining two datasets together on one set of lists but will be styled separately? Is `ListView` the correct control for dealing with multiple kinds of data, or is there something else?

I'm still quite new to this field; apologies if this is a basic concept I can't quite grasp yet.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way and it is quite simple. Make both `Event` and `To-do` inherit from the same base class (could be empty) and create an `ObservableCollection` of this base type (can also be `object` if you do not want to create a separate class). Add both `Event` and `To-do`object to this `ObservableCollection`.

Bind the `ListView` to this `ObservableCollection`. Now comes the tricky part. You need to create a `DataTemplateSelector`. For a compete guide, see http://blog.kulman.sk/using-different-data-templates-with-gridview-in-windows-8-apps/ (this articles is for `GridView` but it works the same for `ListView`).

Comment: How do I define a template based on its class? Say, identify that at a certain point in time the TemplateSelector is working on an `Event` not a `to-do`? How do I call the class name of the object to work with on the override in the post?

Comment: In the post, I use `return (item is MagazineViewModel).IsTop ? BigMagazineTemplate : MagazineTemplate;` just change the test to your classes, like `return item is Todo ? TodoTemplate : EventTemplate`